# Repeating first observation within group with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to repeat the first value within a group across all rows of that group. I had thought his would do it:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(g=c(1,1,2,2), v=c(1,2,3,4)) %>%
    group_by(g) %>% 
    mutate(f=first(v))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: g [2]
#
#       g     v     f
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     1     2     1
# 3     2     3     1
# 4     2     4     1
```

But I don't understand why `f` doesn't return as 1,1,3,3.

Comment: It does return 1 1 3 3 for me.  What dplyr version are you using (`packageVersion("dplyr")`? I have 0.4.3

Comment: Is it possible that `plyr` is also loaded?  In the case, use `dplyr::mutate(f=first(v))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
data.frame(g=c(1,1,2,2), v=c(1,2,3,4)) %>%
    group_by(g) %>%
    mutate(f = dplyr::first(v))
```

You may be picking up `first` from a different package.  It does exist in the `xts` package and likely others.

Comment: Many thanks to all – I've accepted this answer and upvoted Akrun. It turns out I'd previously loaded plyr which was causing the problem.